# PHP Array - accessing specific elements

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way I could access specific array elements below in php? 
I've tried these codes but none seems to work:
1) $array[0]['description']
2) $array->description

```
array (size=5)   'question0' => 
    array (size=7)
      'description' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
      'strCorrectResponse' => string 'Lorem ipsum;' (length=11)
      'strStatus' => string 'incorrect' (length=9)
      'strUserResponse' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=1)
      'nWeight' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nPoints' => string '0' (length=1)
      'nQuestionNumber' => string '1' (length=1)   'question1' => 
    array (size=7)
      'description' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
      'strCorrectResponse' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
      'strStatus' => string 'incorrect' (length=9)
      'strUserResponse' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
      'nWeight' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nPoints' => string '0' (length=1)
      'nQuestionNumber' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: `$array['question0']['description']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the keys down the rabbit hole:

```
$arr = array ('question0' => array('description' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11) 
  |                |                      |
$arr        ['question0']           ['description']
```

```
$arr['question0']['description'] => Lorem ipsum
```